# Rails 2 to Rails 4 Routes Migration - :requirements

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, ruby-on-rails-2

I am upgrading a routes.rb file from Rails 2.3 to Rails 4.

I've been able to upgrade each section's syntax by doing a lot of research. I'm at a resource block I'm trying to upgrade. The current Rails 2 syntax is below:

```
map.resources :profiles do |profile|
    ...
    profile.resources :messages,
                      :requirements => { :profile_id => /[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\@]+/ }
    end
    ...
end
```

How do I convert `:requirements => {...}` to Rails 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requirements` are now called `constraints`. Your example should become

```
resources :messages, :constraints => { :profile_id => /[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\@]+/ }
```

You should also be able to do

```
constraints :profile_id => /[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\@]+/  do
  resources :messages
end
```

which can be more legible